# Max amps/volts for a 7 Segment LCD

Tags: lcd, 7segmentdisplay, maximum-ratings

I recently bought this LCD screen for a project:
https://www.jaycar.com.au/4-digit-field-effect-lcd/p/ZD1886

This LCD screen is just for testing at the moment, the final project will use these (I Hope): http://au.element14.com/lumex/lcd-s2x1c50tr/no-of-digits-alpha-2-5/dp/1703044

I read the specs and both say that they run at about 3V (The second one I believe says 3-5V).

My project is running off of 6V (4 x AA), and I read online that to drive something that requires 3V from a 6V supply, is to put another wire between two of the pairs of batteries:

+6V    +3V     GND
AA AA | AA AA

(I hope the above makes sense).

So back to my initial questions

1) I did a few tests of hooking 3V up to the ground and one of the pins for a decimal place (as I won't be using those so it doesn't matter to me if those parts die), and I noticed that upon disconnecting the LCD section remained in its darkened/visible state for about half a second, and so I was curious and hooked 6V up to another decimal point (again on a second I know I won't need), and it became visible, and still worked afterwards, but it remained darker for about 2 seconds.

Is this caused by the higher voltage actually damaging the insides or what's the go here?  I would have assumed if I put double the recommended voltage, it would have stuffed that segment, or the whole LCD screen.

2) As per the above question the segments remain on for about half a second, while my project won't require quick timing, I want to know if there is an AMP limit (similar to LEDs) and I just can't notice it in the specs, or will I be safe to hook the LCD straight to the supply?

Comment: I also forgot to mention that I plan to drive the LCD screen with these: https://www.jaycar.com.au/4511-bcd-to-7-segment-decoder-driver-cmos-ic/p/ZC4511

Answer (score 1):

Segment displays with a multiplex such as 4:1 or 1:1 use AC signal, in fact DC signal can destroy the LCD in short time. Segments can operate as low as 2.7 volts and as high as 5V.

[Here](https://focuslcds.com/journals/segment-lcd-displays-avoiding-excessive-dc-component/) is an article about the damage DC offset voltage can do to a display and now to avoid it.

Note: I am a design engineer at Focus LCDs and am supplying the link as a supporting document.

Answer (score 0):

All sorted, I discovered LCD screens Require AC power, so I'll be replacing my CMOS 4511 chips with CMOS 4056 chips which support this ability.

Comment: You can mark this as your accepted answer. You can upvote other answers if they were helpful.